# Jquery hover function - how to make this simple?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a blog for a friend and I'm trying to do something very simple.

It's as simple as changing the text on the left as the user mouseovers on each image.

I found some code on other topics, but it doesn't seem the best way to do it, since I'm repeating the same function over and over again, as you can see on the source code.

It works perfectly, but can somebody help me to do it in the right way so we don't have horribly ugly code out there?

I'm a newbie on this subject.

the html code:

```
    <ul>

        <li class="ingredientes_title">busca por<br/><span id="old">ingrediente</span></li>

        <li><a href="/" id="laticinios"><img src="i/ingredientes_02.gif" /></a></li>

        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/" id="paes_e_massas"><img src="i/ingredientes_03.gif" /></a><a href="/" id="frutas"><img src="i/ingredientes_04.gif" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="/" id="doces"><img src="i/ingredientes_15.gif" /></a><a href="/" id="castanhas_frutossecos"><img src="i/ingredientes_16.gif" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/" id="raizes_tuberculos"><img src="i/ingredientes_05.gif" /></a></li>

        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/" id="ovos"><img src="i/ingredientes_06.gif" /></a><a href="/" id="flores_ervas"><img src="i/ingredientes_07.gif" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="/" id="embutidos"><img src="i/ingredientes_12.gif" /></a><a href="/" id="cereais_graos"><img src="i/ingredientes_13.gif" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/" id="aves"><img src="i/ingredientes_08a.gif" /></a><a href="/" id="carnes"><img src="i/ingredientes_08b.gif" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="/" id="peixes"><img src="i/ingredientes_14.gif" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/" id="vegetais"><img src="i/ingredientes_09.gif" /></a></li>

        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/" id="legumes"><img src="i/ingredientes_10.gif" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="/" id="especiarias"><img src="i/ingredientes_11.gif" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

```
</div><!-- /ingredientes -->
```

the js horrible code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#laticinios").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("LaticÃ­nios");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#paes_e_massas").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("PÃ£es e Massas");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    }); 

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#frutas").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Frutas");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#doces").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Doces");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#castanhas_frutossecos").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Castanhas e frutos secos");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#raizes_tuberculos").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("RaÃ­zes e tubÃ©rculos");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#ovos").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Ovos");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#flores_ervas").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Flores e ervas");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#embutidos").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Embutidos");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#cereais_graos").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Cereais e grÃ£os");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#aves").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Aves");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#carnes").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Carnes");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#peixes").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Peixes");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#vegetais").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Vegetais");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#legumes").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Legumes");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });

$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#especiarias").hover(
      function () {
         $("#old").text("Especiarias");
        },
        function () {
         $("#old").text("ingrediente");
        }
        );
    });
```

Comment: I cannot see anything HERE. Please, post relevant code

Comment: I cannot "see the thinghy [sic] here" as it is on some other website.

Comment: Post the question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Post your source code

Comment: Thanks everyone, I posted the code here on the question (I posted a link before so you could actually see what was happening, since it's not so easy to visualize.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that's pretty ugly code. :)

First, you only need to include `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` once. Put everything inside it, where I put the `...`.

Second, the neat thing about jQuery is that you can really easily "get" lots of elements at once as long as they share something unique to them -- like they all have the same class, or are all `<img>` elements.

ALSO, avoid writing accented letters in your HTML; write HTML entity names instead, because otherwise they won't show up properly on many browsers. For example, write `&ntilde;` instead of "ñ". (See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Here's an easy fix:

1. In your HTML, give each of the `img` a "title" attribute with whatever you want the "busca por" to say when the `img` is mouseovered. For example:

   `<li><a href="/" id="laticinios"><img src="i/ingredientes_02.gif" title="latici&ntilde;os" /></a></li>`
2. Replace your JS/jQuery code with this:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#ingredientes ul li a").hover(
   //This activates when any "a" element in a "li" element in a "ul" element in an element with the id of "ingredientes" is mouseovered
       function(){
           var foodType = $(this).children("img").attr("title");
   //This "gets" the value of the "title" attribute of each of the `img` tags and makes it a variable called "foodType"
           $("#old").text(foodType);
       },
       function(){
           $("#old").text("ingrediente");
       }
   );

   });
   ```

I think that'll work.

Comment: Thanks Robert, it looks so much better now. I'm sorry about the ugly code, that's what happens when a designer tries to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting each image with their specific id with jquery. I would set the same css class on every image and use it as a selector to apply your hover function.

Inside that function you could program something to associate you specific text for each image using a list of ids.

This way you would have only a single javascript function in your page.